# How to display multiple dynamic tables on webpage

Tags: php, html, css, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I have an SQL query which shows orders for customers.

I have big screen in the office where I am showing the customers orders.

I am using the boostrap table to show the orders. The problem is some orders have few line items than others. So, this creates a lot of space.

This is how it looks like:

[image: order board]

I want to display orders so I don't get empty space. I want table to adjust them selves.

I also want to view the layout in 4 different columns.

So how to 4 columns of tables; the table can have a different number of rows but they all adjusted nicely so I don't get any white space.

Here is my HTML for the table:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $value["test"]?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value["test"]?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value["test"]?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value["test"]?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value["test"]?></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at masonry

Answer (score 0):

You could use the grid system with Bootstrap in order to define the four evenly spaced columns and then populate each column with DIV's which are 100% in width. The margin bottom would put some white space between the sections, but would not try to align each row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">

      <div style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div>Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div style="width:100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div>Content 2</div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't worked. It replaced the tables with Divs.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a table of tables then. The main table being of four columns and many rows, with each individual table again having four columns and many rows, with each one displaying the customers orders.

So in the code above, you replace the strings "Content X" with individual customers order table. Obviously your code will be making sure that the customers are spread across the four columns in even numbers. Although even that is prone to error, as one column could have 5 customers, each one with 1 order. The last column could have 5 customers, each one with 10 orders.

Comment: Its probably best then to stop using the main table to format the display for the individual tables. Wrap each customer table within a DIV which is 25% wide and then float then all left. At least that way the display will shuffle around to the best of its ability to display all the individual tables.